# Error en la instalación de npm webpack

Tags: nodejs, npm, webpack

Estimada comunidad,

estoy recien empezando con con el mundo nodejs y entre las varias complicaciones que me he encontrado me salta esta que no la he podido sortear.
Cuando intento instalar webpack:

```
npm install webpack --save
```

Después de un rato de instalación me salen unos warning y no lo deja instalado pues cuando intento ocupar el comando webpack (según las instrucciones de un curso), la consola no me la reconoce.

warning:

[image: Imagen consola]

No se que mas hacer. En el package.json quedó así:

```
"webpack": "^3.10.0"
```

me ayudan?

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario instalar `webpack` globalmente (aunque muchas veces hacerlo simplifique la vida). En ambientes donde no tienes permiso para instalar paquetes globalmente, y no es trivial configurar que éstos se instalen en tu home (ej, ambientes de integración continua o pruebas automáticas como Codeship, Travis, CircleCI, etc), igual puedes ocupar `webpack` localmente, sólo que en vez de llamar simplemente a `webpack` lo llamas como

```
./node_modules/bin/webpack
```

(o como sea que se defina el camino relativo en WIN32)

En Linux la abreviación para hacer esto mismo es llamar

```
$(npm bin)/webpack
```

Apuesto a que en windows también puedes evaluar `npm bin` de alguna manera

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado. Seguiré avanzando a tropiezos....

Answer (score 0):

Me responderé solo.

Cuando lo instale de la sgte forma:

```
npm install webpack -g
```

y no

```
npm install webpack --save
```

Me lo dejo bien instalado.

slds